# Sphinx api-doc not putting packages together

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

### Background

My code has the following structure:

```
.
└── my_package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── classif
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── inference.py
    │   └── models.py
    ├── datasets
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── datasets.py
    └── matching
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── elastic.py
        └── search.py
```

After a `sphinx-quickstart` (with `autodoc`) I ran `sphinx-apidoc` as follows:

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -o source my_package -e -M
```

I now have the following files:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── build
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── classif
│   ├── datasets
│   └── matching
└── source
    ├── _static
    ├── _templates
    ├── conf.py
    ├── index.rst
    ├── modules.rst
    ├── my_package.classif.inference.rst
    ├── my_package.classif.models.rst
    ├── my_package.classif.rst
    ├── my_package.datasets.datasets.rst
    ├── my_package.datasets.rst
    ├── my_package.matching.elastic.rst
    ├── my_package.matching.rst
    ├── my_package.matching.search.rst
    └── my_package.rst
```

I also modified `conf.py` to add:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

and added `modules` to the `index.rst`:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   modules

# [more lines]
```

### Now here is the issue

After running `make clean ; make html` I get the warnings:

```
/path/to/my_package.classif.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/path/to/my_package.datasets.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
/path/to/my_package.matching.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

Which makes sense as **sphinx-apidoc did not reference them in `my_package.rst`**. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually known -> https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4446

Upgrading to sphinx `1.7.6` solved it.